# Quantum Mechanics - time evolution after a measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution

> A non-degenerate two-level system is described by a Hamiltonian $\hat H$ with $\hat H|n\rangle = \epsilon_n|n\rangle$, where $n = 1, 2$. An observable $\hat B$ has eigenvalues $\pm 1$, with the corresponding orthonormal eigenfunctions $|\pm\rangle$  related to $|n\rangle$ by

> $|+\rangle = (|1\rangle + 2|2\rangle)/\sqrt{5}$

> $|−\rangle  = (2|1\rangle  − |2\rangle )/\sqrt{5}$

> What are the possible outcomes, together with their probabilities, of a measurement of $\hat B$ in a state of the system with the energy $\epsilon_2$? Would you get the same result if you made a second measurement of $\hat B$ some time after the first?

I think i can do the first part:

$P(+) = |\langle 2|+ \rangle|^2 = 4/5$

$P(-) = |\langle 2|- \rangle|^2 = 1/5$

But after making a measurement the wavefunction collapses into either one or the other so should the the probability be 1 and 0, how does this depend on time?

Comment: Does $\varepsilon$ depend on $n$?

Comment: Yes, should be  ε subscript n, i.e  ε1 doesnt equal  ε2

Answer (score 4):

If you measurement yields $+$, your state will be in the eigenstate of $\hat B$ with eigenvalue $+$.  Thus, for instance, if you obtain $+$ at $t=0$ your system will collapse to 
$\vert +\rangle$.  This becomes your new initial state for the evolution.  The time-evolution is obtained by expanding 
$$
\vert\Psi(0)=\vert +\rangle = \vert 1\rangle \langle 1\vert +\rangle +\vert 2\rangle \langle 2\vert +\rangle
$$
from which 
$$
\vert\Psi(t)\rangle= e^{-i\epsilon_1 t}\vert 1\rangle \langle 1\vert +\rangle +e^{-i\epsilon_2 t}\vert 2\rangle \langle 2\vert +\rangle
$$
Since the time-evolution does not produce an eigenstate of $\hat B$, a second measurement of $\hat B$ would produce 
$+$ with probability
$$
P(+,t)=\vert \langle +\vert\Psi(t)\rangle\vert^2
=\vert e^{-i\epsilon_1 t}\langle +\vert 1\rangle \langle 1\vert +\rangle +e^{-i\epsilon_2 t}\langle +\vert 2\rangle \langle 2\vert +\rangle\vert^2
\ne 1
$$
and likewise for $P(-,t)$.

Comment: so this will give: P(+,t) = |exp(-iE1t/h)/5 + 4exp(-iE2t/h)/5|^2, i take it then that the exp are not cacelled by the mod squared as this would just give a probability of 1.

Comment: correct.  $\vert A+B\vert^2 \ne \vert A\vert^2+ \vert B\vert^2$ so the exponentials will "interfere" and will produce a time-dependent probabilities.